# Configure internet connectivity in Centos 6.4 through wired LAN

Tags: linux, internet

I have a broadband internet connection through Hi-5 service provider in windows 8.1. In windows I connect to the internet after creating a connection and entering user name and password through the wired LAN.
But In Centos 6.4 it shows the `sysp0` for LAN connectivity but I am unable to create the new connection and unable to enter user name and password in the new connection.
How can I connect to the internet in Centos?

I installed only one cd of the Centos 6.4.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please clarify which user name and password you entered and where exactly? Is it the one from your internet service provider (ISP)? Did you install tools from your ISP in windows? Also, let us know exactly what is connected to the LAN (a router perhaps?). Did you get an IP (through DHCP)?

Comment: No, I didn't get an IP address i just got username and password for my ISP and i didn't install any tool of my ISP, i just creating a new connection. I am also not using a router.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try by right-clicking on the network icon and then clicking on "Edit Connections". A list of all internet connections will show up. Then, edit you Ethernet Connection and change the security settings and add some username and password as shown in the screen-shot:

[image]

Try different authentication methods. We don't know which authentication method Hi5 might be using.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I already try this method but that was useless. Any other solution?

Comment: MD5 option is not available.

Comment: @PankajSingh Perhaps you need to install some packages to get all the available authentication methods. Then you can try connecting with different authentication methods. I am not sure what package you might need to install to get all of the available authentication methods.

Comment: @PankajSingh I have updated the image in the answer. All the authentication methods are now visible. Try to get all these authentication methods installed on your CentOS and try all of them.